# How to disable MySQL's cache?

Tags: mysql, cache

So that the same queries will take similar amount of time each time,

this is for developing purpose only

Comment: ...and the operating system's disk cache, and the physical cache on the drive itself... hmm.

Comment: The only real way to get absolute consistency is to reboot and perform exactly the same steps each time.

Comment: This is getting scary, anybody hanging here reboot each time to run a query though? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [MySQL Query Cache Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html) page:

> To set the size of the query cache, set the `query_cache_size system` variable. Setting it to 0 disables the query cache. The default size is 0, so the query cache is disabled by default.

and

> If the query cache size is greater than 0, the `query_cache_type` variable influences how it works. This variable can be set to the following values:
>
> - A value of 0 or OFF prevents caching or retrieval of cached results.

But as others have pointed out, MySQL isn't the only thing doing caching.